# Footer links disappear on mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a footer for my web page, it is requested that the logo is on the left and the links on the right, I managed to do it and it looks fine on desktop, but when I switch to responsive design mode it gets totally messed up from 990px and inferior, at some point (like 350px) the links disappear completely. How could I fix this?

```css
.page-footer {
    background-color: #000030;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.list-footer {
    color: white;
}

.footer-copyright {
    margin-top: -3%;
    margin-bottom: -3%;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="page-footer font-small indigo">

        <!-- Footer Links -->
        <div class="container text-center text-md-left">

            <div class="float-left">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/536/354" alt="LOGO" style="width:200px;height:100px;">
                <br><br>

                <!-- Copyright -->
                <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3" style="color:white">0800-123456
                    info@info.com
                    <p>New York</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Grid row -->
            <div class="row">

                <!-- Grid column -->
                <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">

                    <!-- Links -->
                    <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4 text-center title-mine list-footer">ABOUT</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled text-center">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/about" class="list-footer">Link 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/team" class="list-footer">TEAM</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/faq" class="list-footer">FAQ</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
                <!-- Grid column -->

                <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">

                <!-- Grid column -->
                <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">

                    <!-- Links -->
                    <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4 text-center title-mine list-footer">LINK4</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled text-center">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/mutual" class="list-footer">TITLE2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#!" class="list-footer">LINK 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#!" class="list-footer">LINK3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
                <!-- Grid column -->

                <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">

                <!-- Grid column -->
                <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">

                    <!-- Links -->
                    <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4 text-center title-mine list-footer">Services</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled text-center">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#!" class="list-footer">LINK6</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#!" class="list-footer">LINK5</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#!" class="list-footer">link8</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#!" class="list-footer">link9</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
                <!-- Grid column -->

                <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">

                <!-- Grid column -->
                <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">

                    <!-- Links -->
                    <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4 text-center title-mine list-footer">REPORTS</h5>

                    <ul class="list-unstyled text-center">

                        <li>
                            <a href="#!" class="list-footer">3months</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#!" class="list-footer">6months</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
                <!-- Grid column -->

            </div>
            <!-- Grid row -->

        </div>
        <!-- Footer Links -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="text-center py-3" style="color:white">
                <div class="text-justify">
                    <small>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <i>Idemque diviserunt naturam hominis in animum et corpus.</i> Duo Reges: constructio interrete. <b>Immo alio genere;</b> Non igitur potestis voluptate omnia dirigentes aut tueri aut retinere virtutem. <a href="http://loripsum.net/" target="_blank">Quare conare, quaeso.</a> Nam memini etiam quae nolo, oblivisci non possum quae volo. <b>Venit ad extremum;</b> Si ad corpus pertinentibus, rationes tuas te video compensare cum istis doloribus, non memoriam corpore perceptarum voluptatum; </p>

<p>Est autem officium, quod ita factum est, ut eius facti probabilis ratio reddi possit. Videsne igitur Zenonem tuum cum Aristone verbis concinere, re dissidere, cum Aristotele et illis re consentire, verbis discrepare? Ergo instituto veterum, quo etiam Stoici utuntur, hinc capiamus exordium. <b>Utilitatis causa amicitia est quaesita.</b> At cum tuis cum disseras, multa sunt audienda etiam de obscenis voluptatibus, de quibus ab Epicuro saepissime dicitur. Sed ut proprius ad ea, Cato, accedam, quae a te dicta sunt, pressius agamus eaque, quae modo dixisti, cum iis conferamus, quae tuis antepono. </p>

<p>Traditur, inquit, ab Epicuro ratio neglegendi doloris. <b>Ut aliquid scire se gaudeant?</b> <a href="http://loripsum.net/" target="_blank">De hominibus dici non necesse est.</a> Quid enim me prohiberet Epicureum esse, si probarem, quae ille diceret? <b>Dat enim intervalla et relaxat.</b> <a href="http://loripsum.net/" target="_blank">Si quae forte-possumus.</a> </p>


                            <br><br><br>
                    </small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Copyright -->

    </footer>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <a href=# class=scroll-to-top><i class="fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden=true></i></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```css
.page-footer {
    background-color: #000030;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.list-footer {
    color: white;
}

.footer-copyright {
    margin-top: -3%;
    margin-bottom: -3%;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {

footer h5, footer ul li a {
    font-size: 16px;
}
footer .row{
    flex-wrap: unset;
}
  
} 

@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {

footer h5, footer ul li a {
    font-size: 14px;
}
footer .row{
    flex-wrap: unset;
}
footer .float-left {
    float: none!important;
} 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="page-footer font-small indigo">

  <!-- Footer Links -->
  <div class="container text-center text-md-left">

    <div class="float-left">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/536/354" alt="LOGO" style="width:200px;height:100px;">
      <br><br>

      <!-- Copyright -->
      <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3" style="color:white">0800-123456
        info@info.com
        <p>New York</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Grid row -->
    <div class="row">

      <!-- Grid column -->
      <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">

        <!-- Links -->
        <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4 text-center title-mine list-footer">ABOUT</h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled text-center">
          <li>
            <a href="/about" class="list-footer">Link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/team" class="list-footer">TEAM</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/faq" class="list-footer">FAQ</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <!-- Grid column -->

      <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">

      <!-- Grid column -->
      <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">

        <!-- Links -->
        <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4 text-center title-mine list-footer">LINK4</h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled text-center">
          <li>
            <a href="/mutual" class="list-footer">TITLE2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!" class="list-footer">LINK 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!" class="list-footer">LINK3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <!-- Grid column -->

      <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">

      <!-- Grid column -->
      <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">

        <!-- Links -->
        <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4 text-center title-mine list-footer">Services</h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled text-center">
          <li>
            <a href="#!" class="list-footer">LINK6</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!" class="list-footer">LINK5</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!" class="list-footer">link8</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!" class="list-footer">link9</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <!-- Grid column -->

      <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">

      <!-- Grid column -->
      <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">

        <!-- Links -->
        <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4 text-center title-mine list-footer">REPORTS</h5>

        <ul class="list-unstyled text-center">

          <li>
            <a href="#!" class="list-footer">3months</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!" class="list-footer">6months</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <!-- Grid column -->

    </div>
    <!-- Grid row -->

  </div>
  <!-- Footer Links -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-center py-3" style="color:white">
      <div class="text-justify">
        <small>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <i>Idemque diviserunt naturam hominis in animum et corpus.</i> Duo Reges: constructio interrete. <b>Immo alio genere;</b> Non igitur potestis voluptate omnia dirigentes aut tueri aut retinere virtutem. <a href="http://loripsum.net/" target="_blank">Quare conare, quaeso.</a> Nam memini etiam quae nolo, oblivisci non possum quae volo. <b>Venit ad extremum;</b> Si ad corpus pertinentibus, rationes tuas te video compensare cum istis doloribus, non memoriam corpore perceptarum voluptatum; </p>

          <p>Est autem officium, quod ita factum est, ut eius facti probabilis ratio reddi possit. Videsne igitur Zenonem tuum cum Aristone verbis concinere, re dissidere, cum Aristotele et illis re consentire, verbis discrepare? Ergo instituto veterum, quo etiam Stoici utuntur, hinc capiamus exordium. <b>Utilitatis causa amicitia est quaesita.</b> At cum tuis cum disseras, multa sunt audienda etiam de obscenis voluptatibus, de quibus ab Epicuro saepissime dicitur. Sed ut proprius ad ea, Cato, accedam, quae a te dicta sunt, pressius agamus eaque, quae modo dixisti, cum iis conferamus, quae tuis antepono. </p>

          <p>Traditur, inquit, ab Epicuro ratio neglegendi doloris. <b>Ut aliquid scire se gaudeant?</b> <a href="http://loripsum.net/" target="_blank">De hominibus dici non necesse est.</a> Quid enim me prohiberet Epicureum esse, si probarem, quae ille diceret? <b>Dat enim intervalla et relaxat.</b> <a href="http://loripsum.net/" target="_blank">Si quae forte-possumus.</a> </p>


          <br><br><br>
        </small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Copyright -->

</footer>
<!-- Footer -->
<a href=# class=scroll-to-top><i class="fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden=true></i></a>
```